# video.js dynamic resolution option setup

Tags: javascript, css, html, video.js

I am trying to setup [this plugin](https://github.com/vidcaster/video-js-resolutions) for video.js.

I am extremely new to JavaScript, so I am getting a little confused.

That is where I am implementing video.js:

```
<div class="center">
    <video id="example_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
               controls preload="auto" width="700" height="360"
               poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
               data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="//localhost/series/dynamic/AtomCMS/Sample 720p UHD (Ultra HD) video download.mp4" type='video/mp4'data-res="SD" data-default="true" />
    <source src="//localhost/series/dynamic/AtomCMS/Sample 4k UHD (Ultra HD) video download.mp4" type='video/mp4' data-res="HD" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
            supports HTML5 video
        </a>       
    </p>
    </video>
</div>
```

I have included the `.js` file and `.css` for the resolution plugin in my HTML. I attempted to follow [this](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/plugins.md). How do I implement this plugin?